# How to make a structure of which water flows out at a constant rate?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Is there any way to make a structure of which water flows out of at a constant rate? Any way could be used to build the structure, including 3D printing.

Comment: A hole in a wall will allow water under constant pressure to flow at a constant rate. No 3d printer needed to make a hole, I guess?

Comment: What you need is constant pressure. Check out [*carburetor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carburetor#Float_chamber).

Answer (score 3):

Water flows at a constant rate if it experiences a constant pressure. If you make a two level structure where water from the top (main) reservoir is throttled by a float in the bottom level, you can maintain (almost) constant level in the bottom compartment regardless of volume of water in the top. And a hole in the bottom compartment will give you a constant flow rate.

You could make a structure with more than two levels - each would create better control of the level than the last.

Comment: The key is the float-operated valve. Carburetors have had this for a century.